# Total number of groups of 3 non repeating numbers from a list of 21

Tags: c#

I am making this for a colleague who has a class of 21 students. He needs to break them up during the year into groups of 3 but each group can never have a member who has been in a group with another member.

I have written the program, which gives me an output of 25 groups. But I have no idea if this is the most groups, it seems too few.

How do I go to the next row in the foreach when a student has been with the student being tested before.  Break stops the entire loop, Continue gets marked as redundant. I could have 2 people in the group the first has been with the one being checked, but the second hasn't, so the bool gets reset to false.

```
 else //they have met that person before
                    {
                        IsStudentBeen = true;
                    }
```

Can someone please check to see if my code is correct?

```
        private void BtnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //need to have a list of all students to record all students they have been in a group with
       //output to date = 25 groups

        //All students have a list that contains all the students they have been in a group with before.


        List<string>[] StudentHistory = new List<string>[22];

        //Instantiate the lists = names
        for (int i = 1; i < 22; i++)
        {
            StudentHistory[i] = new List<string>();
        }
        List<string> singlegroup = new List<string>();

        for (int k = 1; k < 21; k++) //get all permutations
        {
            for (int i = k; i < 22; i++)
            {
                string student = i.ToString();
                string StudentToAdd = null;
                //Need to add the first memebr manually or it crashes at the foreach
                if (singlegroup.Count == 0)
                {
                    singlegroup.Add(student);
                    StudentHistory[1].Add(student);
                }
                else
                {
                    bool IsStudentBeen = false;
                    foreach (var AGroupStudent in singlegroup) // for each person in the group
                    { //convert the person to an int to find their history list
                        int GroupStudent = Convert.ToInt32(AGroupStudent);

                        if (!StudentHistory[GroupStudent].Contains(student))
                        {
                            //if the student isn't in the group, and they have never been with the others then add them
                            if (IsStudentBeen == false)
                            {
                                StudentToAdd = student;
                            }
                            //add that person to the history of the others
                            StudentHistory[GroupStudent].Add(student);
                        }
                        else //they have met that person before
                        {
                            IsStudentBeen = true;
                        }
                    }
                    //add the student to the group
                    if (IsStudentBeen == false)
                    {
                        singlegroup.Add(StudentToAdd);
                    }
                    //if the group has reached 3 then print it and clear it for the next group

                    if (singlegroup.Count == 3)
                    {
                        String Group = null;

                        foreach (var item in singlegroup)
                        {
                            Group += item + " ";
                        }

                        lbxOutput.Items.Add(Group);
                        singlegroup.Clear(); //empty the list ready for the next one
                    }
                }

            }
            //  count++;
            // this.Text = count.ToString();
            // }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another SO participant contributed an answer along the following lines:

```
 var students = Enumerable.Range(1, 21).ToArray();
 var groups = new List<int[]>();

 foreach(var s1 in students)
     foreach(var s2 in students.Where(s => s > s1))
        foreach(var s3 in students.Where(s => s > s2))
        {
            int[] a = { s1, s2, s3 };

            bool allowed = true;

            foreach(var g in groups)
            {
               if (g.Contains(s1) && (g.Contains(s2) || g.Contains(s3)) ||
                   g.Contains(s2) && g.Contains(s3))
               {
                   allowed = false;
                   break;
               }
            }

            if (allowed)
            {
                groups.Add(a);
            }
        }
 Console.WriteLine($"groups: {groups.Count}");
```

This answer made/makes sense to me, but was deleted by the original author.
It finds `50` groups of `3` students each, where no pair of groups shares the same pair of students.

---

**Alternative answer:**
(under somewhat different assumptions)

There are 7 teams with 3 students per round. For the next round, no student can team-up with his/her previous `2r` team members, if `r` is the number of rounds so far. Therefore, 25 rounds are not possible. For 21 students, the maximum number of rounds must be smaller than 10.

The following code found 6 rounds:

```
1:  1  2  3 |  4  5  6 |  7  8  9 | 10 11 12 | 13 14 15 | 16 17 18 | 19 20 21
2:  8 12 21 | 20 17  7 |  2 11 15 |  1 16 10 |  4  9 19 | 13  3  5 | 18  6 14
3: 20  2 18 |  5 12 14 |  8 16  4 | 10  7 21 |  6  1 19 |  3 15 17 | 11 13  9
4: 12  9  2 |  5  8 11 |  1 13 17 | 19 10 18 |  3 20 16 |  4 14  7 | 21  6 15
5:  7 19  5 | 14  1  8 | 15 12 20 | 21 16 11 | 17 10  4 | 18  3  9 | 13  2  6
6: 18  8 15 | 13 12  7 |  2 10  5 |  6 11 17 | 19 16 14 | 20  1  9 |  4 21  3

class Program
{
    static Random random = new Random();
    static int students = 21;
    static int studentsPerGroup = 3;
    static int groups = students / studentsPerGroup;
    static List<int[]> history = new List<int[]>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] order = Enumerable.Range(1, students).ToArray();
        int round = 1;

        history.Add(order);
        showOrder(round, order);

        while (++round < 500)
        {
            do
            {
                order = shuffle(ref order);
            }
            while (!allowed(ref order));

            history.Add(order);
            showOrder(round, order);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("ciao!");

    }

    private static bool allowed(ref int[] order)
    {
        for (int g = 0; g < groups; g++)
            for (int i = 0; i < studentsPerGroup - 1; i++)
                for (int j = i + 1; j < studentsPerGroup; j++)
                {
                    int student1 = order[g * studentsPerGroup + i];
                    int student2 = order[g * studentsPerGroup + j];

                    foreach (var ord in history)
                    {
                        int g1 = 0;
                        int g2 = 0;

                        for (int k = 0; k < students; k++)
                            if (ord[k] == student1)
                            {
                                g1 = k / studentsPerGroup;
                                break;
                            }
                        for (int k = 0; k < students; k++)
                            if (ord[k] == student2)
                            {
                                g2 = k / studentsPerGroup;
                                break;
                            }
                        if (g1 == g2)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }

        return true;
    }

    static void showOrder(int n, int[] order)
    {
        string s = string.Format("{0,4}:", n);
        int i = 0;

        foreach(var st in order)
        {
            s += string.Format(" {0,2}", st);
            if (++i % studentsPerGroup == 0)
            {
                s += " |";
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    static int[] shuffle(ref int[] arr)
    {
        return arr.OrderBy(i => random.Next()).ToArray();
    }
}
```

I could not analyze all `21! = 5.1e19` permutations of 21 students. Therefore, I resorted to a random shuffle.

Comment: I deleted my answer because you calculated the number of rounds, so I thought that was the auther of the question needs.

Comment: Yes. Let us wait and see. I found your answer quite convincing and skillful.